# How to create kafka topic with partitions in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using kafka-node [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#kafkaclient) api for creating kafka topics. I did not find how to create a kafka topic with partitions.

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.Client(),
    producer = new Producer(client);
// Create topics sync
producer.createTopics(['t','t1'], false, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
// Create topics async
producer.createTopics(['t'], true, function (err, data) {});

producer.createTopics(['t'], function (err, data) {});// Simply omit 2nd arg
```

how to create kafka topic with partitions in nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

From your node.js app execute the shell script $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh —create —topic topicname —partitions 8 —replication-factor 1 —zookeeper localhost:2181

Where $KAFKA_HOME is the location where you installed Kafka

Comment: You can’t. Not until someone makes a node client that supports the Kafka AdminClient API.

Comment: updating my earlier comment to note that librdkafka now supports the Kafka AdminClient functions so any nodejs Kafka client that exposes those functions should allow creation of topics. https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

As documentation describes, this method works only when `auto.create.topics.enable` is set to `true`:

> This method is used to create topics on the Kafka server. It only works when auto.create.topics.enable, on the Kafka server, is set to true. Our client simply sends a metadata request to the server which will auto create topics. When async is set to false, this method does not return until all topics are created, otherwise it returns immediately.

This means that any operation on unknown topic will lead to its creation with default number of partitions configured by `num.partitions` parameter.

I'm not sure, but maybe one of the `node-rdkafka` implementations could allow you to call corresponding `librdkafka` method to create topic?

Comment: `librdkafka` does not support the topic admin API yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure but I think as per your requirement the code has updated here:- https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node#createtopicstopics-cb, adding a parameter "replicaAssignment".

```
  // Optional explicit partition / replica assignment
  // When this property exists, partitions and replicationFactor properties are ignored
  replicaAssignment: [
    {
      partition: 0,
      replicas: [3, 4]
    },
    {
      partition: 1,
      replicas: [2, 1]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score -2):

The `Producer.createTopics` takes a `partitons` option.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#createtopicstopics-cb

Pass an object, rather than a string

```
producer.createTopics(['t', 't1'], true, function (err, data) {});
```

becomes

```
producer.createTopics(
  [
    { topic: 't', paritions: 5 },
    { topic: 't1', partitions: 23 },
  ], 
  true,
  function (err, data) {}
);
```